# I lied on my resume, how do I fix it?

Tags: background-check

I applied for the position a Software Engineer and cleared the initial phone screens at my dream company. I was asked to complete the job application before the onsite interview and was worried if I would get caught.

I lied about two things, my current title and my internship. I'm currently a Jr. Software Developer, and I mentioned in my resume that I was a Software Developer (although I feel I'm handling the responsibilities of a mid-level Developer). The other thing was that I was an intern for 5 months before I started working full time at my current workplace. I added the internship experience as full time experience.

Instead of mentioning that I was working as an intern from Jan-May 2013 and then from May 2013-Present as a Jr. Software Developer, I mentioned that I worked from Jan 13-Present as a Full time Software Developer.

Is it worth it to fix this now while I'm completing the Job application? Or should I wait till after the interview and tell the HR then? Or not tell at all? Would the HR notice the discrepancy if I make the change now, and cancel my onsite interview?

Edit: I continued my full time position at the same company where I was interning.

Comment: If this truly is your dream company, why lie & risk it? You'll most likely feel guilty, even if it doesn't get noticed at first, and you'll always be at risk for sudden termination in case someone checks it later on. Additionally, you'll most likely feel terrible if this causes you to not get the job. Honesty carries you a long way.

Comment: This is a very loaded question, so honestly, only you can decide for yourself what you should do. However, I can give you advice for the future: Don't do it again :O :D.

Comment: Definitely stop lying and don't do this ever again!

Comment: If you want to fix it you should correct your resume with the correct information and send it to them. Explain that the other one is wrong and say "please refer to this copy instead" or something like that. If they look at the two versions then yes, they will notice the discrepancy. Be prepared to answer questions about why you sent the first one in the form that it was in.

Comment: Thanks Brandin for the tip, I did not want to lie, and do not want trouble later. This is what I plan to do, in the job application I'll attach my updated resume mentioning the internship and my corrected title, and if they question me about it I can maybe explain that I sent the incorrect copy of the resume earlier. Could you suggest a more 'professional' way of doing this. I do not want to accept that I lied. Should I wait and fill the application later, after the interview with the corrections?

Comment: Is there anyway that I can 'get away' with it? Should I use good hire or hire right to run a background check on my self?

Comment: *I did not want to lie* That's BS. Who did the application?

Comment: I did the resume, I'm yet to complete the application. I honestly feel it's semantics, and should not matter. Would really appreciate feedback on how I could go about correcting this?

Comment: @Tesla88 Professional at this point would be to correct it, and own up to your mistake if asked. "In retrospect I should have written the correct information at first, but I was tempted to make my CV look better." If you convince them that you regret the untruth they may accept the explanation.

Comment: @Tesla88 If you think it should not matter then why are you here asking about it and feeling guilty? If it's no problem, then treat it as such. During an interview, if you get one, you might also just mention it casually e.g. "That position actually started as an internship, before being promoted to full-time..."

Comment: It's not that hard to understand a Jr being left off.  It could easily be done by accident.  The intern part is a little more difficult to explain, but I'm not sure how anyone would really know.   I've never been asked for someone's title when I was called as a reference.  Personally, I don't put much thought into titles, particularly in the software industry, since every company has their own set of titles and structure.   Your years of experience will tell them you were Jr level, they have no way to know the company you came from didn't just all everyone Software Engineer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The things you lied on aren't as bad as you make it out to be. Yes you've been done like Kilisi said. However I think it can still be saved.

It's not a huge leap to go from jr software developer to software developer. After all, a jr software developer is ALSO a software developer. so on this part, you haven't really lied.

Next, the time you've worked at the company is still accurate, it simply did not include the setting in which you worked for part of that time. If I was an interviewer and I noticed this, I'd find it somewhat more forgivable as the quantity of work you delivered is true and it also correctly describes the things you've done during that time. Whether it was an internship or not, it's still work.

If it were any other kind of details, you'd have been screwed. However these things seem fairly innocent.

Comment: Thanks Migz for the postivity, I really needed that. I hope they forgive it and I'll probably

Comment: Thanks Migz for that bit of postivity, I really needed that. It's night here and I'm having a hard time sleeping right now!  I feel so guilty! Can you please suggest some ideas on how I could frame it, maybe just plead guilty of ignorance, but that's my last resort.

Comment: @Tesla88 If they were to ask for it, just tell them you wrote down your general role in the company. and that you wrote down the full amount of time you worked there. You could say things such as that you haven't had much experience with writing resume's so you assumed that this was the correct way to write it down. claim it as an honest mistake. If you send them the corrected version, tell them you've had someone else review it and had them make a few suggestions to be more accurate. In the end, you havn't lied about your work experience or type of work you did.

Comment: will do that, hope they'll buy it! :D

Comment: Also, titles are of very little significance.  I have done essentially the same job for 30 years, and had so many different titles (systems analyst, systems engineer, programmer, software engineer, etc).  And one job had me listed as a"Jr Systems Engineer" even though I had ten years of experience, because "we only count the years that you have been with the company".  So don't sweat that part.  The internship has more potential for problems, but just explain to them that you listed your most recent state instead of breaking it out into the various stages of being employed with that company.

Comment: Having been in the software industry for 20+ years, I can say that one company might call you a Jr Software Developer whereas the exact same position at another company would be a regular software developer or even a Sr.  This title difference is trivial.

Answer (score 7):

It's been done already, drawing attention to it will probably get your whole application binned. Just put your head down and be ready to apologise for them misunderstanding your resume if they ever ask.

It's all harmless enough and barely understandable if you just plead ignorance. Admitting you lied seems less appealing to me.

Comment: agreed. the title stuff is trivial, and aren't internships generally full-time anyway?

Comment: @bharal yes, I was working as a full time intern (40hrs/wk)

Comment: @Tesla88 If that's true (on working full-time hours) then you're not lying at all? Think of it as flight training for a pilot: yes, it's training, but it also counts towards total hours in flight. So you have 40*numberOfWeeks amount of experience doing the work. As for title...I wouldn't think too hard. I've had 5 titles in 3 jobs and all were doing the same work. Hell, once my title changed 2 times during the course of employment at the same company and I did the exact same thing the entire time.

Comment: Yep, trivial and easy to rationalise if they even ask. OP isn't going for a CEO job here.